# geometry shader shim for opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es2, geometry-shader

I just have a few months of OpenGL experience, just starting to get the hang of it.

I find geometry/vertex/fragment shaders to be very powerful. You have a few parameters that translates into a complex representation. One layer of your program can compute these parameters, the "model" only, and sharers can do the "view" part. That gives you a good separation of concerns and a lot of flexibility.

It's a pity that OpenGL ES 2 doesn't have geometry shaders. I think the CPU could totally take over this part in case the GPU doesn't support it and if proper shim libraries were present.

Is there any library that helps unfolding a model into vertexes / vertex attribute parameters / uniques, etc? Maybe one that uses the language of the geometry shaders?

Comment: "Is there any library that helps unfolding a model into vertexes / vertex attribute parameters / uniques" Yes but this is a different story than using a geometry shader.

Comment: What's your recommendation? On a side note, I think geometry sharers could totally do the job... but probably it's just a wishful thinking to have such a compatibility library.

Comment: Well depending on what is the job. Regardless there are libraries like http://www.openmesh.org/ but it might be too complex for your task. it all depends on what you want, if your task is simple just do it without a library.